# What is incorrect with my infinite while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

encodec = {
    'a':22 , 'b':24 , 'c':26 , 'd':28 , 'e':12 , 'f':14 , 'g': 16 , 'h':18 , 'i':32 , 'j':34 , 'k':36 , 'l':38 , 'm':42 , 'n':44 , 'o':46 , 'p':48 , 'q':50 , 'r':52 , 's':54 , 't':56 , 'u':58 , 'v': 62 , 'w':64 , 'x':66, 'y': 68 , 'z':72 , ' ':74 , '.':76 , ',':78 , "'":82 , '?':84 , '"':86
}
decodec = {
    22:'a' , 24:'b' , 26:'c' , 28:'d' , 12:'e' , 14:'f' , 16:'g' , 18:'h' , 32:'i' , 34:'j' , 36:'k' , 38:'l' , 42:'m' , 44:'n' , 46:'o' , 48:'p' , 50:'q' , 52:'r' , 54:'s' , 56:'t' , 58:'u' , 62:'v' , 64:'w' , 66:'x', 68:'y' , 72:'z' , 74:' ' , 76:"." , 78:',' , 82:"'" , 84:'?' , 86:'"'
}
option = raw_input("Would you like to 'encode' or 'decode' a word? ")
while option.lower() not in ('encode' , 'decode'):
    option = raw_input("Please enter a valid response ('encode' or 'decode'): ")

if option.lower() == 'encode':
    word = raw_input("Enter a string to be encoded: ").lower()
    length = len(word)
    z = 1
    result = []
    while z < length+1:
        a = word[z-1]
        result += str(encodec[a])
        z = z + 1
    print int(''.join(result))


elif option.lower() == 'decode':
    num = (raw_input("Enter your text to be decoded: "))
    length = len(num)
    z = 1
    result = []
    while z < length+1:
        a = num[z-1:z+1]
        result += str(decodec[int(a)])
        z = z + 1
    print ''.join(result)
```

This is the snippet that won't quite work:

```
elif option.lower() == 'decode':
    num = (raw_input("Enter your text to be decoded: "))
    length = len(num)
    z = 1
    result = []
    while z < length+1:
        a = num[z-1:z+1]
        result += str(decodec[int(a)])
        z = z + 1
    print ''.join(result)
```

I don't understand why this loop continues to loop. The conditional of the loop is that while the value of variable z is less than the value of the length, to continue the loop. The length doesn't increase in the loop, and I add a line in the loop that adds 1 to z every iteration. For some reason, though, it continues to loop infinitely. I dont understand why?

Comment: are the braces "()" enclosing the last raw_input intended? Because they'll turn the input into a tuple instead of string.

Comment: @ManishMulani: No, they won't. You'd need a comma for that.

Comment: You aren't running the code you think you are.  Use the first rule of debugging: When In Doubt, Print More Out.  Add some print statements, for example, to see what is happening to result.

Comment: `result +=`? don't you want `result.append()`?

Comment: For one, I don't even see the infinite loop, for me it just breaks in the end of the row, since it tries to match 1 symbol. And then it would be nice to have some more explanation on what the final achievement should be. Cuz I'm not sure that this implementation does what OP intends it to.

Comment: I can't see how this can possibly result in an infinite loop, and it didn't when I tried it; instead there was an error caused by z being incremented by 1 each time (it should be `z = z + 2` since the codes are 2 characters long)

Comment: probably some spacing problem that offsets where a block starts or ends.

Comment: On top of the spacing problem, it might be worth mentioning that the programme would be simpler if you used `for` loops instead of `while`, and if `result` was a string instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code work for you?

```
elif option.lower() == 'decode':
    num = (raw_input("Enter your text to be decoded: "))
    result = ''
    index = 0
    while index < len(num) -1:
        result += decodec[int(num[index:index +2])]
        index += 2
    print result
```

If I set the input as `222426`, the output is `abc`

Answer (score 6):

Looks like inconsistent use of whitespace to me.  Try running your code using

```
python -tt your_program_name.py
```

to confirm this.  If I look at the raw code you've posted, the first snippet looks like this:

```
 "    elif option.lower() == 'decode':\n",
 '    \tnum = (raw_input("Enter your text to be decoded: "))\n',
 '    \tlength = len(num)\n',
 '    \tz = 1\n',
 '    \tresult = []\n',
 '    \twhile z < length+1:\n',
 '    \t\ta = num[z-1:z+1]\n',
 '    \t\tresult += str(decodec[int(a)])\n',
 '        \tz = z + 1\n',
 "        print ''.join(result)\n",
 '    \t\n',
```

and you can see the strange indentation of the `z = z + 1` line.  In particular, though it seems like you're using tabs for indentation, that line only has one tab, so even though it looks like it's correctly indented on the screen I don't think it's actually being executed because it's not actually inside the `while` loop.

Always use four-space tabs: makes life so much easier.  Most editors can be configured to do this.